# How can I enable https for AWS EC2 web server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

I have already installed nginx, and open 80 and 443 ports.
Now I can open the web page in browser via http.

But failed to open web page via https.

I tried to install  CA-signed certificate using  `certbot --nginx`
finally an error occured:
An unexpected error occurred:

```
Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for "ec2-43-198-203-153.ap-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com": The ACME server refuses to issue a certificate for this domain name, because it is forbidden by policy
```

How could I make this work? Please help, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Install an SSL certificate in Nginx. Just like Nginx running on any other server. There's nothing AWS/EC2 specific about that.

Comment: To be able to get a certificate you need a domain you control.  You don't control `ap-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com` so you can't issue certificates for that domain.   You need to register your own domain (you can do it on AWS Route 53 which I recommend)  and then use that domain for your site so the certificate can be signed or the domain you're using.